# Implement WCF in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, wcf

We have a vb.net application where we have implemented multithreading.  We determined that we need to either implement .net remoting or WCF.  After researching remoting in .NET on MSDN, Microsoft considers remoting legacy for .NET framework 4.0 and recommends using WCF instead.  How easy is it to implement WCF into a VB.NET application?

Update:
We have implementing WCF into our application.  WCF is a very powerful technology and if you're looking to implement and deploy SOA - I highly recommend that you buy some books and research the technology.  It took us about a month to get familiar with the technology and implement it for our needs.

Comment: You need to give details on what you are trying to accomplish using WCF/remoting.  Get specific.  Yes remoting and WCF can be implemented in VB.NET just a easily as C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF was introduced at .Net 3. If your application is .Net 3 or above you can use WCF whether your using VB.Net or C#. If you are using .Net 2 or below, you will have to first port your app to a more recent framework version.